# Want to print dots after loading like print 3 dots and 3 dots disappear and print 3 dots again

Tags: python

What print dots after loading like print 3 dots and 3 dots disappear and print 3 dots again in python. But loading should not repeat pls

Comment: See [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CR to get to the start of the line and use spaces to overwrite the previous dots. This will work:

```py
import time
for _ in range(5):
    for x in range (4): # three dots
        string = "Loading" + "." * x + "   "
        print (string, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
```

---

Maybe is better to use the ANSI Escape to clear the line rather than replace with spaces:

```py
import time

for _ in range(5):
    for x in range (4): # three dots
        string = "Loading" + "." * x
        print("\033[K", string, end="\r") # clear the line, print string and go back to the start
        time.sleep(1)
```

This way, the next normal print to the terminal will overwrite `Loading`.